# Java universal getter/setter or pass attribute as a getter/setter argument

Tags: java, getter-setter

Is it possible to make a class getter/setter that can take any of the class attributes as an argument so as not to have to make a getter/setter pair for each attribute needed?

I am new to Java

For example, is something like this possible?

```
class Someclass {
   int var1;
   int var2;
   int var3;

   public int getanyvar(Attribute varname) {
      return varname;
   }

   public void setanyvar(Attribute varname, int value) {
      varname = value;
   }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
It is unclear what you are asking or what the problem is.
Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description of the problem you have.

Comment: If you want a practical solution to avoid writing boilerplate look either into records or, if using an older version of java, Lombok.

Comment: Federico is referring to for example lombok's [`@Value` annotation](https://projectlombok.org/features/Value) - you just write `@Value class Someclass { int var1, var2, var3; }` and the getters and setters are just there now.

Comment: Note also that this becomes useless if the variables are of different types.

Comment: And it's just bad design as it would expose the internals of the class where callers of the class would have to know the private/protected field names.  Good luck ever refactoring, even a simple field name change would be needlessly difficult.

Comment: You could also try to use reflection to find fields in the class to get or set, but like others have said, this is poor design, and it breaks all type checks of the compiler when you have fields of different data type. [Tell, don't ask](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html) may be helpful, or Records, or even Lombok if you really need to make the details available.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input. This is all enlightening. I did not know that reflection is what I was looking for, but now I understand the cons. For the projects I'll be contributing to, we'll be limited to Java 8 so records won't be an option I think, and Lombok is probably the practical solution I'm looking for aside from just typing out all the methods as everyone suggests.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really recommend this, but you could easily do it with a switch

```
public void setanyvar(String varname, int value) {
   switch (varname) {
   case "var1":
      var1 = value;
      break;
   case "var2":
      var2 = value;
      break;
   case "var3":
      var3 = value;
      break;
   }
}
```

Just make getters and setters for each attribute, I feel like this way of doing things would get annoying and confusing.

Comment: This is a creative approach. For small bits of code I will probably play with this idea, but for production I will likely take your second suggestion.